# Right-continuity of the function $g(t)=\mu(\{x\in A:f(x)>t\})$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, $A\in M$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function on $A$. Show that the function $g(t)=\mu(\{x\in A:f(x)>t\})$ is non-increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ and right continuous in each point.

**My approach:** Let $t_1<t_2$ then $$\{x\in A: f(x)>t_1\}=\{x\in A:f(x)>t_2\}\sqcup \{x\in A: t_1<f(x)\leq t_2\}$$ and since each of those sets are measurable then by $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$: $$g(t_1)=g(t_2)+\mu(\{x\in A: t_1<f(x)\leq t_2\})$$ and hence $g(t_1)\geq g(t_2)$.

Let's show that $g(t)$ is right-continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Let's fix $t_0\in 
\mathbb{R}$ and take the sequence $t_n>t_0$ such that $t_n\to t_0$. Suppose that $E_n:=\{x\in A:f(x)>t_n\}$ for $n\geq 0$. Then it follows that $E_0=\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$. If I can show that $\mu(E_0)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\mu(E_n)$ then I am done.

But I cannot show this. I was trying to apply the continuity of measure $\mu$ but in this case $E_n$ is not a nested sequence.

Please help me to finish the solution.

Comment: I think $E_n$ are nested, because $t_n \geq t_{n+1}$. Therefore, $\{f(x) > t_n\}\subset \{f(x) > t_{n+1}\}$.

Comment: @DaviBarreira, no it's not because $t_n$ is any sequence of real number $>t_0$ which converges to $t_0$. It may not be monotone sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to deal with non increasing sequences.

By $t_n \downarrow t$ I mean a sequence $t_n \to t$ such that $t_n \ge t$ for all $n$.

First note that if $t_n \downarrow t$ then there is a non increasing subsequence $t_{n_k} \downarrow t$. (To see this, note that either $t_n = t $ infinitely often or $t_n >t$ infinitely often. In the latter case,
start with some $t_{n_1}>t$ and select the next element ${1 \over 2}t_{n_1} > t_{n_2}>t$, etc, etc.)

Then we have $g$ is continuous from the right at $t$ **iff** $g(t_n) \to g(t)$ for all non increasing sequences $t_n \downarrow t$.

To see this:

If $g$ is continuous from the right then it is clear that if
$t_n \downarrow t$ then $g(t_n) \to g(t)$.

Now suppose $g(t_n) \to g(t)$ for all non increasing sequences $t_n \downarrow t$. To prove by contradiction, suppose
$g$ is **not** continuous from the right at $t$. Then there is some $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence
$t_n \downarrow t$ such that $|g(t)-g(t_n)| \ge \epsilon$ for all $n$.
Now select a non increasing subsequence as above to get a contradiction.

**Note**: Extracting a non increasing subsequence from $t_n \downarrow t$.

If $t_n = t$ infinitely often then choose this subsequence.

Otherwise $t_n=t $ only happens for a finite number of terms
and after some $N$ we have $t_n >t$ for $n \ge N$.
Then, for any $n \ge N$ we can find some $n' >n$ such that
${1\over 2}t_n > t_{n'} > t$. Repeating this procedure we
can create a strictly decreasing subsequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply! I will try to understand it. What do you mean by $t_n \downarrow t$?

Comment: BTW, you are talking about the directions $\Leftarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$. Sorry but could you explicitly write down what kind of statement you are going to prove. Sorry please but it is not so clear :(

Comment: I made some edits, hopefully this clarifies.

Comment: Probably you meant $t_n>t$ infinitely often in the second case, right? Because it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the mistake & added an elaboration.

Comment: I got it right now because when you wrote that $t_n>0$ infinitely often it confused me a bit that's why i asked my stupid question as usual :) thank you a lot for your help! I appreciate it! :)

Comment: Glad to help (much easier than the other issue), my typing skills are poor.

Comment: You are explaining very well! Believe me.